# Error when connect RSU to OpenFlow Switch in OMNeT++

Tags: runtime-error, omnet++, veins

I want to simulate a VANET based Software Defined Network (SDN).

I successfully integrated SUMO with OMNeT++ using Veins. Then I imported INET, OpenFlow.

An error appears when I added gates to the RSU and connected it with the OpenFlow switch. The error message is below.

How can I fix that and what should I modify to make my Veins scenario work with SDN?

```
<!> Gate 'RSUExampleScenario.rsu[0].In' is not connected to a submodule (or internally to another gate of the same module) -- in module (omnetpp::cModule) RSUExampleScenario.rsu[0] (id=7), during network setup
TRAPPING on the exception above, due to a debug-on-errors=true configuration option. Is your debugger ready?
Simulation terminated with exit code: -2147483645
Working directory: D:/omnetpp-5.1/samples/veins/examples/veins
Command line: ../../../../bin/opp_run.exe -m -n .;../../src/veins;../../../openflow;../../../inet/src;../../../inet/examples;../../../inet/tutorials;../../../inet/showcases --image-path=../../images;../../../openflow/images;../../../inet/images -l ../../src/veins -l ../../../inet/src/INET omnetpp.ini
Environment variables:
PATH=;D:/omnetpp-5.1/samples/veins/src;D:/omnetpp-5.1/samples/inet/src;D:\omnetpp-5.1\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:/omnetpp-5.1/ide/jre/bin/server;D:/omnetpp-5.1/ide/jre/bin;D:/omnetpp-5.1/ide/jre/lib/amd64;.;D:\omnetpp-5.1\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\mingw64\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\usr\local\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\site_perl;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;D:\omnetpp-5.1\tools\win64\usr\bin\core_perl;D:\omnetpp-5.1;
OMNETPP_ROOT=D:/omnetpp-5.1/
OMNETPP_IMAGE_PATH=D:\omnetpp-5.1\images
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated